# List of failed requests in Azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We can see the failed request count in Azure application gateway but how can we see the list of failed requests in the Logs section?

All the logs enabled in Diagnostics settings of Application Gateway.

We need to see at least the requested path (URL) and the response code for the failed requests in the Logs section in the Application Gateway.

Because of the way access log stored in the storage account (folder structure), it is a bit difficult to access the required data through the storage account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by running the following query on the logs, and I have a blog post on the same topic [here](https://www.abhith.net/blog/azure-application-gateway-list-of-failed-requests/)

```sql
// Errors by URI
// Number of errors by URI.
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and httpStatus_d > 399
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by requestUri_s
| sort by AggregatedValue desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#diagnostic-logging), you should see the requested URL and return code in the access log. The [access log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#access-log) is generated only if you've enabled it on each Application Gateway instance. An access log is collected every 300 seconds. Perhaps there is a delay for logs data update.

> Access log: You can use this log to view Application Gateway access
>   patterns and analyze important information. **This includes the caller's
>   IP, requested URL, response latency, return code, and bytes in and
>   out.** An access log is collected every 300 seconds. This log contains
>   one record per instance of Application Gateway. The Application
>   Gateway instance is identified by the instanceId property.

Comment: Because of the way access log stored in the storage account (folder structure), it is a bit difficult to query the required data through the storage explorer.

Looking for a way to query the data through the Logs section in the application gateway. (Updated the question)

Comment: You could find the [query examples](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/robdavies/2017/12/29/monitoring-application-gateway-with-azure-log-analytics/), Is this what you want?

Comment: I did check the mentioned post earlier, but we see the following error if try to query AzureDiagnostics
| limit 50
Error says - SYNTAX ERROR

'take' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AzureDiagnostics'

Comment: Try to search Log Analytics workspace, then query it on your specific log analytics workspace---general----logs instead of access azure application gateway---monitoring---logs, sometimes, the two ways have some delay result. Also, you should see the access logs existence in your enabled storage account.